# How to set the query param from a react component? Without flux or redux

Tags: react-router

I just want to take the value from a search input and fire a function to put the value in the url as a query param.

I've found lots of questions about getting the query param in react-router, but have not seen how to put the query param there from something like a search input. I'm sure it is obvious.

For context, I have a HOC that has access to the query and uses it in a mini-mongo cache query.

Note: I am not using flux or redux. I just need a simple way to set the query from an onChange or onClick.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

React is still Javascript, so you should be able to use any Javascript way of performing this action. For example:

```
function searchButtonOnClick(){
   var userInput = document.getElementById('search-input').value;
   window.location.href += '?userQuery=' + userInput; 
}
```

Set this function as the onClick method of the button and it should work.